# Проблема с запуском ubuntu через grub

Tags: linux, ubuntu

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вчера поработал на linux. Сегодня утром включаю ноутбук через grub выбираю ubuntu, а там появляется эти ошибки. Подскажите пожалуйста что делать?

Comment: Делать именно то, что предлагает текст ошибки — выполнить fsck для проблемного раздела. Консоль уже автоматически открылась, прямо сюда и можно вбить нужную команду

Comment: А что именно вбить?

Comment: Ну например `fsck /dev/sda2` как предлагает текст ошибки

Comment: После fsck /dev/sda2 пишется /dev/sda2 was not cleanly unmounted,check forced. Потом появляются pass 1,через минуту pass 2 3 4,а после 5 идут бесконечные цифры

Comment: Однажды они должны кончиться, а если не кончаются, значит диск окончательно убит, и придётся в лучшем случае переустанавливать систему, а в худшем идти в магазин покупать новый диск

Comment: Но вообще нормально что в passing 5 идут цифры?

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно загрузиться с флешки\cd в любой linux и запустить проверку fsck. Почитайте так же [это](https://askubuntu.com/q/812614/989902) - там описана схожая проблема. И, думаю, стоит подумать о приобретении нового диска.

Comment: Загружаться с флешки/cd необязательно, шелл уже и так открыт (видно приглашение `(initramfs)` на скриншоте) и можно прямо сюда вбить нужный fsck

Comment: А, точно. printk с толку сбил...